# Set a duct type as default option Revit Api 2014

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

I'm new to the Revit API, I am development a wpf interface for something topics in HVAC, I want to set in this interface the default option of duct type in the properties for draw ducts, is it posible in Revit Api 2014 ?, I have tried to create a new instance with type, copy or create similar programmatically, but it doesn't work. I have seen that in the Api 2015 there is a method called SetAsDefaultType
and I don't know if it works for this and if there is any way to recreate it in a development for 2014. Thanks a lot.

[Draw duct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMzML.png)
[Select a duct type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9ICG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Revit API!

Yes, indeed, the [Default Type API](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2015-api.html#3.02) was introduced in Revit 2015.

I am not aware of any possible workaround to achieve the same results in earlier versions.

I would not recommend investing much effort in implementing applications for Revit 2014, since it is very much out of date by now.